# Asymptotic behavior of the real root of $kx^{k+1} -(k+2)x^{k} + 1$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, roots

I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of the largest real root of the following polynomial:
$$ \mathcal{P}_k \colon \quad k x^{k+1} - (k+2) x^k + 1$$

Let $\alpha_k$ denote the largest real root of the polynomial $\mathcal{P}_k$. It is easy to check that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_k = 1$. However, I would like to understand the rate of convergence of the limit. More precisely, I want to either compute the limit exactly,
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_k^k,$$
or find some interval (the smallest possible) so that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_k^k \in [a, b]$. I have no idea whether a similar question was already studied and what tools I could use to tackle this question. From some numerical experiments, I get that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_k^k \in [6.2, 7]$ but can't prove it rigorously.

**How I got there:**
I was analyzing a non-linear problem. After computing its Lagrange multiplier relaxation, I ended up with the polynomial $\mathcal{P}_k$ where $\alpha_k^k$ is the value I am trying to maximize.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My back of the envelope computation suggests that the limit $s$ is the solution of $s(2-log s) =1$, though I may be wrong.

Comment: The limit given by Aleksei can be expressed in terms of the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): $s=-1/W(-e^{-2}) \approx 6.30539$

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov May I ask how you managed to get this value only from computations?

Comment: @Toufik well, computation means a short argument with a lot of boring technical holes that any sophomore should be able to fill:) the argument is as follows: if $\alpha_k \approx 1 + \frac{c}{k}$, then the limit is $s = e^c$. Plugging these values in we get $ks (1 + \frac{c}{k}) - (k+2)s +1 \approx 0$, which gives the desired equation for $s$ since $c = \log s$.

Comment: I thought you managed to find the limit using a computer. But yes, your first answer was sufficient :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$ P_k(x)=x^k(kx-k-2)+1$$
and 
$$\begin{align} P_k'(x)&=kx^{k-1}(kx-k-2)+kx^k\\&=kx^{k-1}((k+1)x-(k+2)),\\
\end{align}$$
so that $P_k$ can have local extrema at most at $x=0$ and $x=1+\frac1{k+1}$. From $P_k(0)=1$, $P_k(1)=-1$, $P_k(1+\frac2k)=1$, the last  critical point must be a minimum and in particular $P_k(1+\frac1{k+1})<-1$.
We conclude
$$ 1+\frac1{k+1}<\alpha_k<1+\frac2k.$$
This give us
$$\tag1e\approx \left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)^k<\alpha_k^k<\left(1+\frac 2{k}\right)^k\approx e^2.$$
If we define $x_k\lesssim y_k$ as "For all $\epsilon>0$, for almost all $k$, $x_k<y_k+\epsilon$", then this can be written as 
$$ e\lesssim\alpha_k^k\lesssim e^2.$$
Note that $$\tag2\alpha_k^k=\frac1{2-k(\alpha_k-1)}.$$ 
We can make this last step more precise:
Suppose we have $a,b$ such that 
$$a\lesssim\alpha_k^k\lesssim b. $$
Then from $(2)$, we conclude 
$$1+ \frac{2-\frac1{b}}k\lesssim \alpha_k\lesssim 1+ \frac{2-\frac1{a}}k$$
and so 
$$ e^{2-\frac1b}\lesssim \alpha_k^k\lesssim e^{2-\frac1a}.$$
Starting with $a=e$ and $b=e^2$, we obtain quite small intervals after a few iterations. The intervals converge to a point $y$ with $e^{2-\frac1y}=y$.

Comment: Thank you for this neat and precise solution. This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\ln{\alpha_k}=\beta_k$. Then $e^{k\beta_k}(k+2-ke^{\beta_k})=1$. So $1 \leq \alpha_k \leq 1+2/k$. Thus $e^{\beta_k} = 1+\beta_k+r_k$, with $k^2r_k \leq C$. Therefore, taking logarithms, one finds $k\beta_k+\ln(2-k\beta_k-kr_k)=0$. In particular, $k\beta_k+\ln(2-k\beta_k)> 0$, so it follows $k\beta_k < 1.9$.

As $kr_k \rightarrow 0$, it implies that $\frac{2-k\beta_k-kr_k}{2-k\beta_k} \rightarrow 1$. Therefore $k\beta_k+\ln(2-k\beta_k) \rightarrow 0$. Thus, the limit $\ell$ of $\alpha_k^k=e^{k\beta_k}$ satisfies the equation $\ell(2-\ln{\ell})=1$, as Aleksei Kulikov's comment tells.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of Aleksei's answer. I think there are missing parentheses.